# How does Hinduism explain about Aliens or Dinosaurs?

Tags: vedas, scripture, belief, gods, science

I know we have Vedas and other sacred writings which explained many things even before scientific discoveries were made like distance of sun, rotation and revolution of earth etc.

But what and how does those scriptures explain about Aliens and Dinosaurs?. We are pretty sure that they exists or existed and how is it explained?.

I have this feel that hinduism or be it any religion and very idea of God were all put forward only after the evolution of humans. I am not denying the existence of god or completely agree about the existence. I am just curious to know and find relation in whatever I understand.

Comment: First, Patanjali explains evolution in his 'Yoga Aphorisms' that life evolved from lower to higher forms. This question/answer is already in another question on this site. Second, aliens. This question is of a speculative nature as no aliens have yet been found yet to exist. Questions of a scientific speculative nature are not allowed on this site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the first part of the question is a duplicate, the second part is scientific speculation and off topic.

Comment: Personally, I believe that "aliens" are "higher density beings." Some see them as aliens, other see them as celestial beings & demons, among other things, depending on a person's specific illusions.

Comment: Since this was closed for being a duplicate of a question regarding aliens, perhaps you should rewrite your question to be only about dinosaurs and/or other extinct creatures.